# How to insert a number into an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

Ok I am trying to do the following using an array.

Say I have one array

1 4 3 7 8

and at index 1 I want to place a 2 to get the following

1 2 4 3 7 8

How do I do this I think I have to make one array to keep everything before the index, one array to keep everything after the index.

And the add one more element to the array with everything before the index. The create a new longer array with everything before the index and everything after the index.

But I cannot seem to do it. This be what I tried.

//this program will test out how to replace an array with more stuff

```
public class Raton
  {
     public static void main(String[] args)
 {
        int[] gato={1,4,3,7,8};
        int[] perro = new int[gato.length+1];
        int[] biggie = new int[gato.length];

         int index=2; //store item index 2

    System.out.println("the contents of gato are ");

    for(int i=0; i<gato.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(gato[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<gato.length;i++)
    {
        if(i<index)
        {
            perro[i]=gato[i];
        }
        else
        {
            int red=0;
            biggie[red]=gato[i];
            red++;
        }
    }

    //put two in the new place

         for(int i=0;i<perro.length;i++)
         {
           System.out.println(" \n the contents of peero are " + perro[i]);

      }
          for(int i=0; i<biggie.length;i++)
        {
        System.out.println("\nthe contents of biggie are " + biggie[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using arrays (over other data structures), you'll need to create a new array and set the old one to it.

Comment: Assuming this is homework or otherwise learning about arrays - think about why do you need `biggie` (hint: you don't)?  You already have an array that is big enough to hold all the original numbers plus the new one in `perro`.  Can you see how you might fill the rest of `perro` correctly?

Comment: Not is not homework I am just trying to do this as practice for a project. But I cannot seem to figure it out, but yes I need arrays not arraylist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get both the new number and new index.

```
int newNumber = 2;
int newIndex = 1;
```

Create the new array with size+1 of old array

```
int[] gato = {1,4,3,7,8}; //old array
int[] perro = new int[gato.length+1]; //new array
```

Then keep track of of two counters. `j` for old array and `i` for new array.

```
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<perro.length; i++){
    if(i == newIndex){
        perro[i] = newNumber;
    }
    else{
        perro[i] = gato[j];
        j++;
    }
}
```

Here's a [test run](https://ideone.com/VMFggl). This solution is assuming you have a constraint where you can only use arrays (not `ArrayList` or any other prebuilt classes in Java)

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of arrays, they allow easy insertion of new elements, and arraylists allow that at specific indices too.

```
int[] gato={1,4,3,7,8};
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(gato));
list.add(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code, but something similar should do the trick.

```
public class Raton {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] originalArray = {1,4,3,7,8};
        int[] modifiedArray = new int[originalArray.length + 1];

        int index = 2;

        for(int i = 0; i < (originalArray.length + 1); i++) {

            if(i==1) {
                modifiedArray[i] = index;
            }
            else if(i < 1){
                modifiedArray[i] = originalArray[i];
            }
            else {
                modifiedArray[i] = originalArray[i-1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at the "before" and "after" arrays:

**Before**

```
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│1│4│3│7│8│
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
 0 1 2 3 4
```

**After**

```
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│1│2│4│3│7│8│
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

One thing you already noticed is that you need a target array that is 1 bigger than the original array. That's correct.

But you have several problems in your program.

1. You copy all the parts that are before the `index` to `perro`. Since `perro` is your target array (the one bigger than the original), you have to make sure that everything gets copied to it. But instead, you only copy the parts that are before the `index`.
2. You want to place the 2 at index `1`. But you wrote `index=2`. This means that both the `1` and `4` will be copied to `perro` consecutively. Your `perro` will look like this:

   ```
   ┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
   │1│4│0│0│0│0│
   └─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
    0 1 2 3 4 5
   ```

   and this means that you didn't put the `2` in the place you wanted it. That place is taken by the `4`.
3. You try to copy the numbers after the `index` to `biggie`. But you are doing this using `red`. And in each iteration of the loop, you set `red=0` again. So the only place in `biggie` that will change is `0`, and that place will get all the numbers, and the last one will stay. So your `biggie` will be:

   ```
   ┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
   │8│0│0│0│0│
   └─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
    0 1 2 3 4
   ```
4. You don't put the `2` anywhere!
5. You don't copy things from `biggie` to `perro` so you don`t get all the parts of the array together.

So let's look at our `before` and `after` arrays again:

**Before**

```
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│1│4│3│7│8│
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
 0 1 2 3 4
```

**After**

```
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│1│2│4│3│7│8│
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

So first, we have to remember that the `index` we want to change is `1`, not `2`. Now look at the `after` array. You notice that there are three types of numbers:

- Ones that stayed in the same place (the `1`)
- Ones that were added (the `2`)
- Ones that moved one place to the right (`4`,`3`,`7`,`8`)

How do we know which of the original numbers "stay" and which ones "move"? It's easy. The ones whose index is less than `index` (remember, it's `1`!), that is, the one at index `0`, stays.

All the others (including the one that is in the `index` itself!) have to move to a new place. The place is their old index + 1.

So your program should look like this:

- Prepare an array whose size is one bigger than the original (like your `perro`).
- Loop on all the indexes in the old array. Suppose the loop variable is `i`.

  - If i is *less than* the `index`, copy the number at index `i` from the original array to the new array at the same index, that is, at `i`.
  - For all other cases, copy the number at index `i` from the original array to the new array, but moved by one place. That is, `i+1`. There is no need for another variable or a `++` here.

  When you finish that loop, your array will look like:

  ```
  ┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
  │1│0│4│3│7│8│
  └─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
   0 1 2 3 4 5
  ```
- Now don't forget to put your actual `2` there, at the `index` index!

**Note:** please give your variables meaningful names. I'm not sure, perhaps the names are meaningful in your native language, but `biggie` and `red` seem to be words in English, but they don't help us understand what these variables do. Try to use variable names that describe the function of the variable. Like `original`, `target`, `temporary`, `nextIndex` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a clean and simple solution :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] gato = {1, 4, 3, 7, 8};


    int index = 2; //store item index 2

    System.out.println("the contents of gato are ");

    for (int i = 0; i < gato.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(gato[i]);
    }
    gato = Arrays.copyOf(gato, gato.length + 1);

    for (int i = gato.length - 1; i > index; i--) {
        gato[i] = gato[i - 1];
    }
    //put the element in the array
    gato[index] = 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < gato.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(gato[i]);
    }
}
```